# Can I delete system reserved?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm currently dual booting windows 7 and ubuntu (both x64). I was able to make it work after using boot-repair via liveCD.

I was wondering if I can delete windows' system reserved partition, now that I'm using grub; so that I can make a swap partition for my ubuntu because I want to enable hibernate, and I learned after searching that it requires a swap partition.

I already have 4 partitions :( Windows, System Reserved, Ubuntu, My Files(Partition //NTFS) So, would windows still work if I delete System Reserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100MB partition is a system partition and contains boot files. Disk Manager will not allow you to remove this partition because removing this partition could cause the system to not boot providing that Windows 7 or Windows 8 on a MBR drive.

Now that being said, **Do not attempt to delete on UEFI systems where Windows is installed on a GPT drive.**.

Now if that's not the case, or you're on windows 7 then take a look at [Deleting Windows 7 System Reserved Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/448640/deleting-windows-7-system-reserved-partition)

Comment: I don't even know how my PC works as UEFI because it doesn't even have an option in my BIOS to make it UEFI instead of LegacyBIOS. When trying to boot discs, "Press any key to boot CD/DVD" shows twice, but both looks different. I noticed that the first one is for EFI and the second is the normal one, because when I press a key on the first one, it detects my PC as UEFI, and when I boot on the second one. It works normal. Anyway, I reinstalled everything. Was able to install windows without system reserved, and then install ubuntu, then enabled its boot via boot-repair. Thanks, btw :)